# CSS mouse hover fallthrough

Tags: html, css

I have 2 text element, and when mouse hover the middle of them, I need both mouse hover events to be triggered. 
This is my code:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
.div1 {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s;
  transition: left 2s;
  left: 10px;
}
.div2 {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  transition: left 2s;
  left: 50px;
}
.div1:hover {
  left: 100px;
}
.div2:hover {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">paifjopweijfopaiwjef</div>
<div class="div2">fpaowiejfoaweafjweoi</div>
```

When mouse enter the overlap region of the 2 elements, I want to trigger both transitions. 
The second `div` transition is working, but the first one doesnt work. It seems the mouse hover event does not "fall through". So how can I trigger both?

Comment: when mouse enter the intersection region of the 2 div, i want to trigger both transition.

Comment: @Trix I've edited the question.

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if this is the desired output. do u still need them to act separatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
}
.div1 {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s; 
    transition: left 2s;
    left: 10px;
}
.div2 {
    display: block;

    background: green;
    transition: left 2s;
    left: 50px;
}

.parent:hover .div1{
    left: 100px;
}
.parent:hover .div2{
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">paifjopweijfopaiwjef</div>
  <div class="div2">fpaowiejfoaweafjweoi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your both of your `div` elements in yet another `div` and detect `:hover` on the parent as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    position: absolute;
}
.div1 {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s; 
    transition: left 2s;
    left: 10px;
}
.div2 {
    display: block;

    background: green;
    transition: left 2s;
    left: 50px;
}

div.parent:hover .div2 {
    left: 0px;
}
div.parent:hover .div1 {
    left:100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">paifjopweijfopaiwjef</div>
    <div class="div2">fpaowiejfoaweafjweoi</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```